# How can i completly destroy session. if session not availbale redirect to login page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, redirect

Hello i am trying to destory session when i press signout button then it's logging out and redirecting to login page; but `when click back in browser that page is loading with loign menu on top.`

And i have wrote a code in everypage as if session not available redirect to login page.

Here is my logout code for session_destroy:

```
elseif(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']== "logout" )
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:index.php');
        } else {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION = array(); 
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

here is the code what i have mentioned in all pages:

```
session_start();
include_once('includes/config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

So my question is completly logout if press back it should not load and has to redirect to login page.

Comment: Have you added headers? like `Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['id']){
unset($_SESSION['id']); // destroys the specified session.

}

header('Location:index.php'); //redirect to preferred page after unset the session

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_destroy()
```

By this function you can destroy all session at browser. If you work with php you should write :

```
    ob_start (); 
session_start();
```

By this your buffer also flush and new start session. Try with it.

Comment: @Baheerbagh .. Its ok. I have given just an example. But important thing is ob_start() use .

Answer (score 1):

Create a page like **signout.php**, And set **signout** button link to this page.

**Example**

```
<a href="signout.php">Signout</a>
```

Add below codes for **signout.php** page.

```
session_start();   #Start new or resume existing session
#session_unset($_SESSION['key']); #Free specific session variable if you want, OR
session_destroy(); #Destroys all data registered to a session
header('location:login.php'); #Redirect to login page after logout
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try in this way :**

```
session_start();

unset($_SESSION["id"]);

session_destroy();
header('location:index');
```